# Problem with CSS postion: relative with position: absolute children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

Usually this sort of thing I can do, but today it is bugging me.

See [this](http://jsbin.com/uyepo/) page at JSbin.

Essentially what I'm doing is

- have a list of unordered items
- they all have a link
- jQuery loops through and makes an extra link inside the list item, which is expanded to the whole list item using CSS
- this gives users a larger place to click

For some reason, the child link seems to be coming out of the parent, despite the parent having `position: relative`.

What have I done wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the `display: -moz-inline-box;` and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the parent `<li>` is an inline-box.

To fix it, [replace `display: inline-box` with `float: left`](http://jsbin.com/uyepo/2/edit).

Comment: I ended up removing the Mozilla vendor prefix'd property, and not having to resort to floats.. see my answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 there you go SLaks... however I believe your answer is more of a workaround then a proper solution. The way I ended up handling it seems better.